# Numpy setuptools: How to compile fortran file as part of a module

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, setuptools, f2py

I have a directory structure of the form

```
setup.py
python/
  __init__.py
  a.py
  b.f
```

I'd like to install this as a package called `foo` with the structure

```
site-packages/
  foo/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.so
```

but I'm at a loss as to how to write `setup.py` in order to achieve this. So far I have

```
import numpy.distutils.core
b = numpy.distutils.core.Extension(name = 'b', sources = ['python/b.f'])
numpy.distutils.core.setup(
  name = 'foo',
  version = '0.0',
  packages = ['foo'],
  package_dir = {'foo':'python'},
  ext_modules = [b]
)
```

But this results in

```
site-packages/
  foo/
    __init__.py
    a.py
  b.so
```

So clearly I'm missing something here. How go I get `b.so` to go in the `foo` package rather than being installed as a separate pacakge?

Answer (score 2):

To tell setuptools that a given extension module should be installed as part of package (e.g. `foo`) rather than on its own, it's sufficient to prefix `foo.` to its name. E.g. change

```
b = numpy.distutils.core.Extension(name = 'b', sources = ['python/b.f'])
```

into

```
b = numpy.distutils.core.Extension(name = 'foo.b', sources = ['python/b.f'])
```